# Why is my computed property not computing?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, computed-properties

Below is a single-file Vue.js template. The `note` object is passed to the template as a prop, and includes `audio_length` and `id`.

```
<template>
    <span v-show="note.audio_length > 0" class="audio-element-wrapper">
        <audio controls preload="none">
            <source :src="audioURL" type="audio/webm">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
        <span>
        ({{note.audio_length}}s)
            </span>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    mounted: function() {
        console.log("mounted audioelement", this.note.id);
    },

    props: ['note'],

    computed: {
        audioURL: function() {
            return "/notes/getAudio/" + this.note.id;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

However, when I load the component, the computed `audioURL` results in `/notes/getAudio/undefined`. Apparently, it runs before the `note` property is loaded. The code inside the curly braces is interpreted correctly. How can I bind the `src` property to the correctly computed url?

Comment: make sure you passed note in the parent component like <component-name :note= "value"></component> otherwise you will get this error.. and also are check your browser console. for this.note

Comment: I am calling the template with syntax you describe. When I run the template, the text in the curly braces renders correctly. `{{note.audio_length}}` appears as expected. The console shows `mounted audioelement undefined`

Comment: just log the whole this.note instead of this.node.id so that you will see the whole json object. i am suspecting it might not have id key

Comment: Can you show how the value of the prop is set in the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. It turns out that the problem isn't really with Vuejs *per se*. It's a browser issue. Even though the `src` element was actually modified, it doesn't update the action of the element until you call `.load()`

So, the solution that worked was as follows:

```
<template>
<span v-show="note.audio_length > 0" class="audio-element-wrapper">
    <audio ref="player" controls preload="none">
        <source :src="audioURL" type="audio/webm">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
<span>
</template>
```

And then, in the scripts:

```
updated: function() {
    this.audioURL = "/notes/getAudio/" + this.note.id;
    this.$refs.player.load();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 (vue 2.x)

If you want to pass the object properties as a props then you have to use `v-bind` directive, see the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props) here.

I suppose in your parent component you have something like that for data property:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    note: {
      audio_lenght: 100,
      id: 12
    }
  }
```

Then write your component as:

```
<your-component v-bind='note'></your-component>
```

And in YourComponent.vue:

```
...
props: ['id', 'audio_lenght']
...

computed: {
    audioURL: function() {
        return "/notes/getAudio/" + this.id;
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

Write your component as:

```
<your-component :note='note'></your-component>
```

In YourComponent.vue:

```
props: {
  note: {
    type: Object
  }
},
computed: {
  audioURL: function() {
    return "/notes/getAudio/" + this.note.id;
  }
}
```

Comment: using v-bind without a prop simply binds the whole object to the component. The colon-notation is shorthand for v-bind. In this way, I can have the object and not pollute the namespace.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative solution (Solution 2). I dont think that the v-bind colon shortcut works when the prop is an object, at least I'm not able to pass an object with the colon shortcut. I hope it make more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose is not working because your **audioURL** computed value return a path without your file format.

try to change your computed:

```
computed: {
    audioURL: function() {
        return "/notes/getAudio/" + this.id + ".webm";
    }
}
```

For a better debug i advise you to install vue-devtools

Comment: Thanks. I'm using vue-devtools. When I open the component, it has all the data present. Also, the file doesn't end in .webm. `/notes/getAudio/1` is a REST endpoint.